# Not sure why my code to check if a number is prime is not working?

Tags: python, string, decimal, primes

I need to create a program to check whether a number is prime that first prompts the user to enter a number and then input a string of up to 3 characters. If more than 3 characters are entered via the keyboard, the program should output the message and exit. If a non-numeric character is entered via the keyboard, the program should output the message Invalid input and exit. If the input is valid, the program should display either the
message number entered is a prime number or the message number entered is not a prime number.

I currently have the code to determine whether the number is prime but it does not seem to work, it does not give an output of "is a prime number" when the number entered is prime. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with the prime number code?

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print("is not a prime number")
                break
    else:
            print("is a prime number")


str = input('Please enter a decimal number: ')
try:
    n = int(str)

    if len(str) > 3:
        print ('Invalid input')
    sys.exit()

    if isPrime(n):
        print ('Number entered is a prime number')
    else:
        print ('Number entered is not a prime number')
except:
    print ('Number is not a prime number')
```

Comment: Are you asking how to test if a number is greater than 3?

Comment: So you are asking how to tell if the `len`gth of a string is greater than 3?

Answer (score 1):

with the input() command you prompt the user to give u an input. What u get is an string.
Then u can turn this to an integer and make different cases.
NOTE: if u enter a float number the int(str) will blow up and u will get a message
invalid input. Maybe u should also include a case where u check out if the input is a number, but not an integer.

```
import sys

def isPrime(n):

    for i in range(2, n):
        if (n % i) == 0:
                return False

    return True

str = input('Give an integer, with no more than 3 digits: ')
try:
    n = int(str)

    if len(str) > 3:
        print ('Invalid input! Up to three digits!')
        sys.exit()

    if isPrime(n):
        print ('Is prime')
    else:
        print ('Not prime')

except:
    print ('Invalid input! Not a number')
```

Comment: hopefully this did the job :)

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing, the output does not seem to be "is prime" if the number actually is prime though? For example if you input 2 it says not prime

Comment: hey I noticed that you changed your isPrime() function. I also edided the code above according to your algorithm and now seems to be working fine for the value 2. Hopefully this will solve it :)